# Unable to access react js simple app with istio on k8s desktop

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

Reactjs is simple default application, trying to access through istio but it is unable to access.
Below is the code for deployment used.
docker file
**dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

kubernetes deployment file v1 and v2
**Deployment.yaml**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: my-react-app-v1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-react-app
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-react-app
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-react-app
          image: xxx/react_sample:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
      restartPolicy: Always

---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: my-react-app-v2
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-react-app
      version: v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-react-app
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-react-app
          image: xxx/react_sample:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
      restartPolicy: Always

---
##########################
#Service
##############
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-react-app
spec:
  
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      name: http
  selector:
    app: my-react-app
```

Istio gateway configuration, Virtual service configuration and destination rules.
**Istio Configuration**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: appinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway 
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: appinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - appinfo-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: my-react-app
        subset: v1
      weight: 50 
    - destination:
        host: my-react-app
        subset: v2
      weight: 50
---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: my-react-app
spec:
  host: my-react-app
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

Comment: Are your pods running? Do you have istio-injection enabled on the namespace (optionally, do you have istio-proxy containers injected)? Can you share your application? It would make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: pods are running and istio-injection is also enabled on namespace

Comment: How do you access your app? I deployed an example app myself, and have no problems accesing it with your manifests.

Comment: @p10I  but my site is not loading, How can i debug istio? I checked the logs for pod no errors